# Loop over one array and check if element exist in another array

Tags: php

I have two arrays, the first one is

```
$practice_areas = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1, 
        "name" => "Administrative",
        "form_id" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Admiralty & Maritime",
        "form_id" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "Agricultural",
        "form_id" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4,
        "name" => "Alternative Dispute Resulution",
        "form_id" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 5,
        "name" => "Antitrust & Trade Regulation",
        "form_id" => 1
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 6,
        "name" => "Appellate Practice",
        "form_id" => 1
    )
);
```

and the second one is `$selected_id`

```
$selected_id = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "lawyer_id" => 2,
        "practice_area_id" => 3
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "lawyer_id" => 2,
        "practice_area_id" => 4
    )
);
```

And this is my current code:

```
<label>Practice area(s) *</label>
<select id="practice_areas" multiple="multiple" name="practice_areas[]">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<?php foreach($practice_areas as $practice_area) {?>
    <option value="<?php $practice_area['id'] ?>" <?php ($selected_id->practice_area_id == $practice_area['id']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php $practice_area['name'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I want to select all the options that exist in the `$selected_id` array. I'm having a bad time on writing this loop correctly.

**EDIT1**

when I try to use the

```
foreach ($selected_id as $sel) {
    $is_selected[$sel["practice_area_id"]] = true;
}
```

I've got this result.

```
$selected_id = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "lawyer_id" => 2,
        "practice_area_id" => 3
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "lawyer_id" => 2,
        "practice_area_id" => 4
    ),
    true,
    true
);
```

Comment: Please add the code directly and not as an image.

Comment: `<?php ($selected_id->practice_area_id == $practice_area['id']) ? 'selected=""' : ''; ?>` just try this `selected=""`

Comment: @devpro it's not cause the $selected_id is array too

Comment: which php version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```php
<label>Practice area(s) *</label>
<select id="practice_areas" multiple name="practice_areas[]">
    <option value="" selected></option>

<?php
// First create an array that is keyed by practice_area_id for selected items
foreach ($selected_id as $sel) {
    $is_selected[$sel["practice_area_id"]] = true;
}
foreach($practice_areas as $practice_area) { 
?>
    <option value="<?= $practice_area['id'] ?>"<?= 
                  (isset($is_selected[$practice_area['id']]) ? ' selected>' : '>') .
        $practice_area['name'] ?></option>
    </option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

Note that you had several `<?php` tags that did not echo anything inside the `option` tags. You can use instead the `<?=` tag for that.

Also the `selected` attribute in an `option` does not require a value. Just its presence is enough. The same goes for the `multiple` attribute of the `select` tag.

Finally, the `->` operator only works on objects, but you have arrays, so you should use the bracket notation throughout.

See the above code run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/533148)

Comment: what I did was create new array

Comment: I added a link to eval.in in my answer, so you can see it works. What you added in your question as an edit does not make sense. That  output does not correspond to the code. Note that that loop changes *$is_selected*, not *$selected_id*. I think you are confusing them. Anyway, check out the output generated by [eval.in](https://eval.in/533148).